# Jquery Json Array response not printing in Div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am posting my order id to a php page through AJAX and I am getting json response.
I need to show that in my track order page below snippet i am trying but i am getting error `TypeError: obj.map is not a function.`
I tried putting `var htmlText = obj.response_data. map(function(o)` still i am getting error. How do i print the json response in my DIV
trackorder.php

```
<div class="track-order-response">
</div>

$.ajax({
    url: '<URL>/trackordercompute.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: order_id,
    success: function( data ){

    var obj = $.parseJSON( data );
            var htmlText = obj.map(function(o){
              return `
                  <div class="div-conatiner">
                  <p class="p-name"> Transdate: ${o.Transdate}</p>
                  <p class="p-loc"> Transtime: ${o.Transtime}</p>
                  <p class="p-desc"> deliveredTo: ${o.deliveredTo}</p>
                  <p class="p-created"> Remarks: ${o.Remarks}</p>
                 <p class="p-uname"> Location: ${o.Location}</p>
                 </div>
              `;
            });

        $('.track-order-response').html( htmlText );
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
        $('.track-order-response').html( errorThrown );
    }
    });
```

trackordercompute.php

My JSON RESPONSE

```
echo '
{
    "result": {
    "requested_data": {
    "AuthCode": "XXXX",
    "OrderNumber": "INV374837"
},
"response_data": [{
    "Transdate": "11/02/2019",
    "Transtime": "10:15",
    "StatusCode": "POD",
    "deliveredTo": "Rajendran",
    "Remarks": "",
    "Location": "Sharjah"
    },
    {
    "Transdate": "11/02/2019",
    "Transtime": "08:20",
    "StatusCode": "OD",
    "deliveredTo": "",
    "Remarks": "OUR FOR DELIVERY",
    "Location": "Dubai"
    },
    {
    "Transdate": "10/02/2019",
    "Transtime": "20:10",
    "StatusCode": "AF",
    "deliveredTo": "",
    "Remarks": "ARIVED AT SERVICE CENTER",
    "Location": "Dubai"
    },
    {
    "Transdate": "10/02/2019",
    "Transtime": "11:00",
    "StatusCode": "C",
    "deliveredTo": "",
    "Remarks": "Airway Bill Check In",
    "Location": "Dubai"
    }]
}
}
';
```

Comment: Because `map` is for arrays but it seems like the `data` returned is an object. Have you tried `obj.response_data.map(...)`?

Comment: Yes I have tried. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

What Worked is ForEach instead of map

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'trackordercompute.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: order_id,
                success: function( data ){

                var obj = $.parseJSON( data );
                var htmlData="";
                obj.result.response_data.forEach((o) => {
                    htmlData +=`
                      <div class="div-conatiner">
                      <p class="p-name"> Transdate: ${o.Transdate}</p>
                      <p class="p-loc"> Transtime: ${o.Transtime}</p>
                      <p class="p-desc"> deliveredTo: ${o.deliveredTo}</p>
                      <p class="p-created"> Remarks: ${o.Remarks}</p>
                     <p class="p-uname"> Location: ${o.Location}</p>
                     </div>
                  `;
                });

                $('.track-order-response').html( htmlData );
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                    $('.track-order-response').html( errorThrown );
                }
            });
```